# What are my options to replace a sliding glass door screen?

Tags: replacement, screens

I have a sliding glass door off my kitchen which used to have a screen on it (the screen slid on a track just outside of the glass doors).  When I moved into my house the screen that was there was a replacement screen (I do not think it was the original) which quickly ripped (the screen that was there just was not made for 4 kids 6 years and under).  I tried another replacement screen from Home Depot this spring and although the screen itself did not rip, it just did not fit perfectly, would not slide smoothly, and got bent and went in the garbage in about 2 weeks.

I would try another replacement but it would need to be something better than what I got at Home Depot last.  And I would go to the door manufacturer but the name on the glass is Guardian and I have not been able to find them.

UPDATE (2011-09-18): The patio door is an [American Craftsman by Andersen sold at the Home Depot](http://www.homedepot.com/Doors-Windows-Screen-Doors/American-Craftsman-an-Andersen-Company/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ4wwZbchd/R-100064057/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053).  See [my answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/what-are-my-options-to-replace-a-sliding-glass-door-screen/8986#8986) for more info.

Comment: Jeff you ever find out the name of your actual door manufacturer? My sliding door only has Guardian printed on the glass also. I am trying to get a good replacement screen as well. Thanks for any input.

Comment: @Jax - No, I did not find a replacement yet.  Right now we have no screen... and lots of flies always getting in the house. :(

Comment: @Jax - I finally figured this out!  It is an American Craftsman door (by Andersen).  The screens are sold at Home Depot.  See my answer below - http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/what-are-my-options-to-replace-a-sliding-glass-door-screen/8986#8986

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out!  The door is an [American Craftsman](http://www.americancraftsmanwin.com/productDetail.cfm?MID=5500&cat=DR&type=Patio), which is a contractors line of windows and doors by Andersen sold at Home Depot.  You can buy the screen by itself at the Home Depot: 
[American Craftsman, an Andersen Company 34-1/2 in. Aluminum White Insect Screen for Patio Doors](http://www.homedepot.com/Doors-Windows-Screen-Doors/American-Craftsman-an-Andersen-Company/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ4wwZbchd/R-100064057/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053)

The screen is a perfect fit in my door even though my door was installed 15 years ago.  They have two sizes (widths) available either the 30" wide (for a 5 foot door) or the 36" wide (for a 6 foot door).

Answer (score 5):

Guardian is the manufacturer of the glass itself, but not the door assembly.  See http://www.guardian.com/en/na/gd_002563.html

I think the key to finding the proper sliding screen is going to be finding out the manufacturer of the assembly.  Have you looked all around the door frame for a nameplate?

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing out that Guardian is the glass manufacturer.  I have not seen another manufacturer name on the door but I will take a much harder look today and see if there is one.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look into some 3rd party [retractable screen doors](http://www.google.com/search?q=retractable%20screen%20doors) - there are a number of different manufacturers, and you can probably pick up a universal fit at your local home improvement store.

I've seen a couple of these installed, and the good quality ones are pretty slick, and will handle kids & dogs - when hit, they simply retract.

You should be able to find similar products at your local door & window specialty shop.

Comment: Could you please update the link, and perhaps add search terms, or manufacturer and model information so if the link breaks again we know what to look for?

Answer (score 1):

Did the door that was there when you moved in work ok? Could you just replace the screen in it?

Comment: The screen and the frame were pretty much shot.